# Stopping ClickableSpan on a TextView from changing text color

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a TextView that I need to customize using a `ClickableSpan`, `ForegroundColorSpan` and a `CustomTypefaceSpan` (I created) so it looks so:

[image]

Now I had no problem getting the look right by creating a `Spannable` and applying the `ForgegroundColorSpan` and `CustomTypefaceSpan` to it.

My problem is with the `ClickableSpan` and `LinkMovementMethod`. Both **Rachel Grey** and **Master** have links. By default clicking the link highlights it and darkens the rest of the text.

By setting `textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);` I was able to get rid of the highlighting but the rest of the text is still darkened.

[image]

I also set `textView.setFocusable(false);` but that had no effect.

I'm overwriting the `ClickableSpan`'s `updateDrawState(..)` and `onClick(..)` methods so I'm pretty sure that the fault does not lie there.

```
    ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan()
    {
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint tp)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget)
        {
            Toast.makeText(SpanActivity.this, "Text Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

How do I stop the text from being darkened when I click the TextView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a way to fix this. Explicitly setting the `TextView`'s color fixes this.
So by setting:

`android:textColor="@color/white"`

in the layout xml will stop the text from going all dark on you when it's clicked.